# Supply location in sparse MSIX packages

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, msix

I have a MSIX package that must be deployed with "external content", hence in the manifest the property `<uap10:AllowExternalContent>` is set `true`.

To install it for the current user, `Add-AppPackage` does the job just fine:

```
Add-AppPackage <msix> -ExternalLocation <path to external sources>
```

Now, I want to deploy this MSIX to all users. So far I have understood that `Add-AppxProvisionedPackage` must be used, in fact, it does work if no external content is used:

```
Add-AppxProvisionedPackage -online -packagepath <msix> -skiplicense
```

But it is a requirement that some files of the package are external. How can I provision the package to all users while pointing to the external location? Is there any other alternative?